# Spring MVC MultiActionController index method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I m learning how to use spring with multiactioncontroller.

For now I have a single controller, defined like this:

```
    <bean name="/products/*" class="com.neo.ProductsController">
    <property name="methodNameResolver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="/products/add">add</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

I would like to know three things:

1) How can I create an url like this: **website.com/products** that maps to a method named "index"
I know that I can make it like this:
`<prop key="/products/">index</prop>`, but this is website/com/products/ <-- extra slash

2) If i use multiactioncontroller, how can I make use of PathVariable, for example:
website.com/products/view/4. (REST STYLE)
I know how to make this with annotations @RequestMapping("/products/view/{id}", but I could not find same functionality with multiactioncontroller.

3)What do you recommend, use Annotations or xml to define controllers ? I think it's an advanced way using xml configuration .

Thanks

Comment: Which version of spring ate you using?

Comment: spring-framework-4.0.0.M1

Comment: If you're using Spring 4 I would strongly urge you to use annotations to map controllers!

Comment: I know that using annotations it's easier, but I thought that xml provides a better way to organize information especially in big projects with many controllers. So xml controllers mapping will be deprecated in future ?

Comment: I think that having the mappings away from the code is likely to make it harder to manage. However it's personal preference. It seems for your use case you know how to achieve it using annotations but not XML? Suggests annotations might be the way forward...